# Global.asax events not firing in IIS 7 Integrated Mode with .net 4 routing

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-routing

I just switched over to using Server 2008/IIS 7.  I am running my application in integrated mode.  I am using the .Net 4.0 routing feature and using extension-less urls.

My problem is that the events in the global.asax file that are after the BeginRequest don't fire.

The events fire if I hit my page using an .aspx extension but not when it doesn't have an extension.

Does anyone know what I have to do to get the Application_AcquireRequestState event to fire for routed, extension-less urls in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the events in Global.asax only fire for requests that are processed by the standard `HttpHandler` (objects derived from the `Page` class).

To receive events for every request, you should create and register an `HttpModule`.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Sample
{
    public class SampleModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.AcquireRequestState += OnAcquireRequestState;
        }

        void OnAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```